# Register subclass to an ABC class inside __init_subclass__ does not fully work

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, abc

What I want to achieve is to register one type as subtype of all other types. For some other reason I cannot use metaclass, so `__init_subclass__` seems like a reasonable choice.

I have code like this

```
from abc import ABC


class AnyData(ABC):
    pass

class BaseData(ABC):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.register(AnyData)

class DataA(BaseData):
    pass
```

However `issubclass(AnyData, DataA)` returns `False`, until the `DataA` is subclassed, like

```
class DataB(DataA):
    pass
```

Now, `issubclass(AnyData, DataA)` returns `True` and `issubclass(AnyData, DataB)` returns `False`

Please help to reveal the reason why it behaves like this?

Comment: You want to dynamically add superclasses to another class?

Comment: Curious. If you call `issubclass(AnyData, cls)` from inside `__init_subclass__`, it returns `True`. Calling `cls._dump_registry()` inside `__init_subclass__` also confirms that `AnyData` is registered, but calling `DataA._dump_registry()` shows the registry is empty again, until you define `DataB`.

Comment: However, `issubclass(AnyData, BaseData)` becomes true after defining `DataA` as well, and I don't see why that should *ever* be true, since `BaseData.register` doesn't seem to ever be called.

Comment: Note, though, that `_dump_registry()` indicates that weak references are used. Since `cls` goes out of scope after `__init_subclass__` returns, that could be related.