# Type subclass from inside the parent class

Tags: python, typing, mypy

Suppose we have the following class:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class BaseSwallow:
    # Can't get the ref to `BaseSwallow` at runtime
    DerivedSwallow = NewType('DerivedSwallow', BaseSwallow) 

    def carry_with(self, swallow: DerivedSwallow):
        self.carry()
        swallow.carry()

    def carry(self):
        pass

class AfricanSwallow(BaseSwallow): pass

godOfSwallows = BaseSwallow()
africanSwallow = AfricanSwallow()

africanSwallow.carry_with(godOfSwallows)  # Should fail at static typing
```

I want to enforce that `carry_with` should only be called with instances of classes **derived from** `BaseSwallow`, so I use `NewType` to do that [like the doc says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#distinct).

However, `NewType` needs a reference to the base class object to work, and I don't have access to that at runtime. Before runtime, I have "access" to `BaseSwallow` thanks to the `annotations` module but it will still fail when running.

I'm aware that using an Abstract Base Class for `BaseSwallow` is the best thing to do here in most cases, but I can't do that [for various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59638421/5989906).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to express "all subclasses of `T` excluding `T`" using type annotations. If you have a fixed set of subclasses you could use a `Union` type to capture them all, but that's probably not what you want. I think [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62220325/4909228) is your best bet: just use the `BaseSwallow` base class instead of crafting a complicated type to rule out the base class itself.

Also, I think you misunderstood the usage for `NewType`. `NewType` is used to create an alias of a type that requires explicit conversion. For example:

```py
URL = NewType('URL', str)

def download(url: URL): ...

link_str = "https://..."  # inferred type is `str`
link_url = URL(link_str)  # inferred type is `URL`
download(link_str)  # type error
download(link_url)  # correct
```

---

**Edit:** If you don't mind a little bit of overhead, you can achieve this with an additional level of inheritance. Create a subtype of `BaseSwallow` (named `Swallow` for convenience), and have all the derived classes inherit `Swallow` instead of `BaseSwallow`. This way, you can annotate the `carry_with` method using the `Swallow` type:

```py
class BaseSwallow:
    def carry_with(self, swallow: 'Swallow'):  # string as forward reference
        self.carry()
        swallow.carry()

    def carry(self):
        pass

class Swallow(BaseSwallow): pass  # dummy class to serve as base

class AfricanSwallow(Swallow): pass

godOfSwallows = BaseSwallow()
africanSwallow = AfricanSwallow()

africanSwallow.carry_with(godOfSwallows)  # mypy warns about incompatible types
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :) `NewType` declares one type to be a subtype of another. [...] which means a value of type Original cannot be used in places where a value of type Derived is expected. c.f. [newtype's bottom note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype)
That's exactly the mechanism I want, but it can't work with traditional inheritance for the reasons you've outlined...

Comment: You're right, `NewType` essentially creates a subtype, but it's only for type annotations purposes and has no runtime effect. This means it's not a class that you can inherit from; it's basically an identity function at runtime. If you don't mind a little bit of overhead, I added a new solution in my answer that might suit your needs.

Comment: I agree this works well for all purposes. It's sadly not very elegant, but that's the best we can do right now I guess

Answer (score 0):

can you just mark `carry` as an [`abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)?  for example, something like:

```
import abc

class BaseSwallow:
    def carry_with(self, swallow: BaseSwallow) -> None:
        self.carry()
        swallow.carry()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def carry(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError('implementation of carry needed')
```

derived classes could then implement the method, but because the base class didn't attempts to instantiate it would cause type checking to fail saying that `BaseSwallow` is an abstract class due to missing attribute `carry`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However this breaks `godOfSwallows.carry_with(africanSwallow)` which should work since `africanSwallow` is indeed a `DerivedSwallow`, but in your example `godOfSwallows.carry` is not implemented either.